# display a timer using progressBar xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, timer, xamarin.forms

how to add a nice timer
xaml :

```
 <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                    IsVisible="true"
                    Progress="0.0"
                    WidthRequest="300"
                    HeightRequest="20"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">
                </ProgressBar>
```

**behind code**:

```
progressBar.Progress = 0;
await progressBar.ProgressTo(1.0, 90000, Easing.Linear);
```

Comment: you need to use a Timer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a timer to increment the `ProgressBar`:

```
var updateRate = 1000 / 30f; // 30Hz
double step = updateRate / (2 * 30 * 1000f);
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(updateRate), () =>
{
    if (progressBar.Progress < 100)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => progressBar.Progress += step );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Then you can use an `IValueConverter` to convert the progress to a minute:second style format:

```
public class CountDownConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double time = 0;
        double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out var totalTime);
        double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out var progress);
        time = progress <= double.Epsilon ? totalTime : (totalTime - (totalTime * progress));
        var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time);
        return $"{timeSpan.Minutes:00;00}:{timeSpan.Seconds:00;00}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Tying it together with XAML:

```
<Label
    BindingContext="{x:Reference progressBar}"
    Text = "{Binding Progress, StringFormat='{0:P0}'}"
    HorizontalOptions ="Center"
    FontSize="20"
    FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue"
    TextColor ="Red" />
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar"
    IsVisible="true"
    Progress="0.0"
    WidthRequest="300"
    HorizontalOptions="Center">
</ProgressBar>
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference progressBar},
                      Path=Progress,
                      Converter={StaticResource countDownTime},
                      ConverterParameter=120000}}"
    HorizontalOptions ="Center"
    FontSize="20"
    FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue"
    TextColor = "Red" />
```

Output:

[image]

Update:

You have to define a `ResourceDictionary` to have an instance of the `CountDownConverter` class created and named so you can reference it in XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <tools:CountDownConverter x:Key="countDownTime"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And the `tools:` namespace reference is based upon the C# namespace and assembly that contains the `CountDownConverter`. I have a bunch of these `IValueConverter` classes in a separate library and thus my `xmlns:tools` looks like:

```
xmlns:tools="clr-namespace:Converters;assembly=Converters"
```

re: [Resource Dictionaries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries/)

Comment: Thank you so much @SushilHangover ! I got an error on this line . I know is because I havent define this resource . how could I fix it :  Converter={StaticResource countDownTime},

Comment: what I am trying to say is that I got this error: Cannot assign property "ConverterParameter": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property., and maybe it was because I didn't set this resource correctly ?.Thank you for reply

Comment: Amazing solution, the only problem for me is that the refresh rate its wrong it's not actually seconds so the time shown on the label is not correct

Comment: @JoseManuelOjeda Not sure I understand if you had a problem or not, solved it?

Comment: well everything worked well but the progress bar speed and percentage was too fast it was not showing real seconds, I change it like this           
                float updateRate = 1000;
  TotalTimeInMillisecons=120000
                double step = updateRate / TotalTimeInMillisecons;
                TimeSpan Interval = 
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(updateRate);

Comment: What code would I change to make the progress bar progress faster?

Comment: @11thal11thal Faster? It is based upon actual time, the `updateRate` and frequency to update the progress base (`step`). So I do not understand your question....?

Comment: I am trying to make the progress bar appear for a certain amount of time (let's say 5s), and make the progress bar steadily increase until 100% over those 5s. so I am only using the first part of the answer (use a timer to increment the ```ProgressBar```). I am not sure how to change the speed at which the progress bar increases.

Comment: @11thal11thal If you have a fixed time period 0 to 5 seconds and want to update the UI at a 30Hz (33ms) rate, than 5 * 1000 / 33 = 151 steps. Since a progress bar values are 0 to 100, 100 / 151 = 0.66 step increase every 33ms.