# How to display a timer using ProgressRing xamarin forms with dynamic time

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have implemented a progress ring with time using code referenced from [display a timer using progressBar xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733152/display-a-timer-using-progressbar-xamarin-forms).

Now I want to bind the value of total time dynamically so that when the time reaches some fixed value, the progress ring starts progressing. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ConverterParameter` is not a bindable property, we can't use `Binding`. But we can try to customize this label with a bindable property and pass itself to the `ConverterParameter`.

**Customize this label like:**

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    public double TotalTime
    {
        set { SetValue(TotalTimeProperty, value); }
        get { return (double)GetValue(TotalTimeProperty); }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty TotalTimeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TotalTime), typeof(double), typeof(MyLabel), default(double));
}
```

**Then we can pass itself in the XAML:**

```
<local:MyLabel x:Name="MyLabel" 
                TotalTime="{Binding TotalTime}"
                Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference progressBar}, Path=Progress, Converter={StaticResource countDownTime}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference MyLabel}"
                HorizontalOptions ="Center"
                FontSize="20"
                FontFamily = "Helvetica Neue"
                TextColor = "Red" />
```

**At last modify this `TotalTime` in the code behind:**

```
public class BindModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    double totalTime;
    public double TotalTime
    {
        set
        {
            totalTime = value;
            onPropertyChanged("TotalTime");
        }
        get
        {
            return totalTime;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
// And set this model as a BindingContext 
var model = new BindModel { TotalTime = 60000 };
BindingContext = model;
```

**Also your IValueConverter should be like this:**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    double time = 0;
    double myTotalTime = ((MyLabel)parameter).TotalTime;
    double.TryParse(myTotalTime.ToString(), out var totalTime);
    double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out var progress);
    time = progress <= double.Epsilon ? totalTime : (totalTime - (totalTime * progress));
    var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time);
    return $"{timeSpan.Minutes:00;00}:{timeSpan.Seconds:00;00}";
}
```